# How to get Google Chat ID in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker, google-chat

I am using AppMaker I would like to get the Chat ID of a user so I can open a chat window in a new tab to that user.  However, I don't see a way to get it.

To be clear, I want the part at the end of a URL like this:

```
https://chat.google.com/u/0/dm/pUR6NABBAAE
```

For some reason this ID is different from the old Hangouts chat ID (which I get from the Person datasource).

Is there a way to do this?  I have looked at the docs and searched StackOverflow but do not see anybody trying to do this.

Comment: Nope. I have been trying to get this for a long time now, couldn't find any way. If a user sends a message then you can get this using `event` object.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do what you want as of now.

Google is always [receiving Feature Requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for their APIs so you could try submitting it there.

However, since the Hangouts API is directed at Bots and Google has a compromise to not create avenues for spammers, I doubt that will be implemented.

Comment: Surely there can be a way to allow this without enabling spammers.  I only want to do this within my organization, so for a start they could limit it to that. Oh, Google.

Comment: @Scott feel free to file a Feature Request for that with that information in it.